# Redirect To another Page while using URL Mapping PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using URL Mapping and i manage to do that, but when i'm gonna redirect after certain value it say "This webpage has a redirect loop"

.htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

index.php

```
<?php
function getCurrentUri()
{
    $basepath = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), 0, -1)) . '/';
    $uri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($basepath));
    if (strstr($uri, '?')) $uri = substr($uri, 0, strpos($uri, '?'));
    $uri = '/' . trim($uri, '/');
    return $uri;
}

$base_url = getCurrentUri();
$routes = array();
$routes = explode('/', $base_url);
/*foreach($routes as $route)
{
    if(trim($route) != '')
        array_push($routes, $route);
}
*/
$arrLength =count($routes);
echo $base_url;
echo '<br>jumlahnya '.$arrLength;

for($x=0;$x<$arrLength;$x++)
{

    echo 'data ke '.$x.$routes[$x].'<br>';
}

echo '<br>datanya adalah : '.$routes[0] .'<br>';





if($routes[1] == 'search')
{
    if($routes[2] == 'book')
    {
    header('Location: booklist.php');    

        exit();
    }
}?>
```

when i enter `http://domain.com/search/book/harrypotter` the url change into `http://domain.com/search/book/harrypotter/booklist.php` and it say this webpage has a redirect loop what i want is redirect to `http://domain.com/booklist.php` 
can someone help me solve this?

thanks

Regards

Danz

Comment: If that URL should be handled by booklist.php you have 2 easy options if not more, **A)** fix your route so that it does not redirect to secondary files but handled it there like codeigniter and other frameworks do **or B)** make the `.htaccess` rule specific to booklist.php instead of index.php

Comment: You can change your PHP redirect to this: `header('Location: /booklist.php');` This way, you're using absolute path instead of relative path

Comment: thx for your answer i managed to solve this question using include syntax :)